# She has a unique personality

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, visual, rebus, geography

Each square is one word, and each row also has a one-word answer.

The **final answer** is what I tell everyone whenever my sister is coming to town.

#1

> [image]
>   <sub>Image credits: 1. Mickayyy, CC BY-SA 4.0; 2.1 Uwe Dedering & TUBS, CC BY-SA 3.0; 2.2 Huhsunqu, CC BY-SA 3.0</sub>

#2

> [image]
>   <sub>Image credits: 1.2 Itub, CC-BY SA 3.0; 2. GibsPado & Sogeking, CC BY-SA 2.5; 3. Fir0002, CC BY-SA 3.0</sub>

#3

> [image]
>   <sub>Image credits: 1. Flominator, CC BY-SA 2.5; 3. Emoji One, CC BY-SA 4.0</sub>

#4

> [image]

#5

> [image]
>   <sub>Image credits: 2. Tracey Nolan, CC BY-SA 2.0</sub>

#6

> [image]
>   <sub>Image credits: 2. fremantleboy & Lokal_Profil & Marmelad, CC BY-SA 2.5</sub>

#7

> [image]
>   <sub>Image credits: 1. Lee Haywood, CC BY-SA 2.0; 2. Richard Bartz, CC BY-SA 2.5</sub>

#8

> [image]
>   <sub>Image credits: 3. Jomafemag, CC BY-SA 4.0</sub>

#9

> [image]
>   <sub>Image credits: 2.1 Fred Hsu, CC BY-SA 3.0; 2.2 Frank Vincentz, CC BY-SA 3.0</sub>

#10

> [image]
>   <sub>Image credits: 3.1 Thomas Pintaric, CC BY-SA 3.0</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like we got there in the end; what a journey! Thanks for the excellent puzzle!

1:

> **Santa Monica Landmark** -> **Pier**
>  Santa, Mon (Myanmar) + Ica (Peru), Land + Mark

2:

> **Noble Majestic Month** -> [August](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/august)
>  elbow backwards with W (tungsten) replaced by N (nitrogen), Ma(g=jest<s>er</s>)ic, Moth "eats" N

3:

> **Dollhouse Victor Actor** -> **Enver** (Gjokaj)
>  Dollhouse, Tango-Uniform-?-Whiskey (Nato alphabet), <s>tr</s>actor

4:

> **First British Martyr** -> **St. Alban**
>  Fist clutches maritime flag "R", [BBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC), [Marty McFly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marty_McFly) + r

5:

> **Architect Lloyd Wright** -> **Frank**
>  Arch+I+(pro)tect, Andrew *Lloyd* Webber, W (on the) right.

6:

> **East Siberia River** -> **Lena**
>  Compass rose, Map of Siberia, R+IV+e+R (+picture)

7:

> **Ride Board Comb** -> **Over**
>  Bride minus B (the hex digit hex B is 11, which is 1011 in binary), Boar + D, Tomb with T -> C

8:

> **Actress Jennifer Jason** -> **Leigh**
>  AC+tre+ss, "Vaccine Edward"=Jenner + "if" in the middle, Jason with the Golden Fleece

9:

> **Garage Yard Clearance** -> **Sale**
>  Garage, Vineyard minus vine, Cl + ear + (l)ance

10:

> **Thousand Ship Launcher** -> **Helen** (of Troy)
>  Number in a 1000 yen note, Flag-|battle-|leader-|oneupman- ship, LA+UN+Cher

Observation:

> Looks like there's a theme of "almost state capitals" going on in there:
>
>  1. Pier -> Pier**re**, South Dakota
>  2. August -> August**a**, Maine
>  3. Enver -> **D**enver, Colorado
>  4. St. Alban -> Alban**y**, New York
>  5. Frank -> Frank**fort**, Kentucky
>  6. Lena -> **He**lena, Montana
>  7. Over -> **D**over, Delaware
>  8. Leigh -> **Ra**leigh, North Carolina
>  9. Sale -> Sale**m**, Oregon
>  10. Helen -> Helen**a**, Montana

And finally, the missing letters spell out

> ***"Ready for the drama."***

Comment: Okay, I'll share mine, too. But it's not only a lot to solve, also a lot to type.

Comment: @MOehm I'll wikify

Comment: Okay, if you don't mind. It might be easier to just edit my stuff in.

Comment: Oh! That's _much_ better.

Comment: Nice work, guys!